# Парсим и выводим каждый блок отдельно

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Есть сайт, на котором в блоке `info` содержатся статьи, мне нужно спарсить все 15 статей, и вывести только 3.
Делаю так:

```
public class IndexActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

String popTovar;
String name;
String allPopTov;
final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.popular_tov);


    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Document doc = null;
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect("http://m.21vek.by").get();
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Elements popTovAll = doc.select("div.info");

            for (int i = 0; i < popTovAll.size(); i++) {
                    Element temp = popTovAll.get(i);
                    list.add(popTovAll.text()); // Добавляем поочередно каждый элемент в массив

            }

            print(); //вызываем метод

        }
    }).start();

}

private void print() {
    System.out.println(list.get(0));
    System.out.println(list.get(2));
    System.out.println(list.get(1));

}

}
```

И все бы хорошо, НО, при выводе получается что я три раза вывожу все статьи. То есть, в методе `print` у меня три раза есть вывод строки:

```
    System.out.println(list.get(0));
    System.out.println(list.get(2));
    System.out.println(list.get(1));
```

И получается что в каждой строке выводит все статьи который в блоках `info`.
Прошу помощи в решении данной проблемы.

Comment: проверили list? там все элементы отделно?

Comment: @SaidolimDjuraev Простите, я предоставил весь код приложения, не могли бы вы по подробнее. Я с android не очень разбираюсь. Я web разраб., а тут появилась такая задача

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вроде проблема тут

```
for (int i = 0; i < popTovAll.size(); i++) {
                Element temp = popTovAll.get(i);
                list.add(popTovAll.text()); // Добавляем поочередно каждый элемент в массив

}
```

а должна быть так

```
for (int i = 0; i < popTovAll.size(); i++) {
                Element temp = popTovAll.get(i);
                list.add(temp.text()); // Добавляем поочередно каждый элемент в массив

}
```

или

```
list.add(""+temp);
```

здесь вы каждый раз добавляете полный текст командой `popTovAll.text()` а нудно добавить значение переменной `temp`

Comment: Огромное спасибо вам!